# How to display html table code in script?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a simple html bootstrap which I can display the html blo code returned by a django view.py render function the following code:

```
<h2 class="mb-4" style="text-align:center"></h2> 
{{table|safe}}
```

and it works perfectly.

But I need to print several tables in a for loop, so I looked for a script mode. In this case it returns the html code as a string.

The code below:

```
<script>
const tabela = {{table|safe}};

document.write(tabela);
</script>
```

EDIT:
My views.py looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    content = {}
    content['table'] = resultados_html #resultados_html is a html block code. Currently it's just one table.
    return render(request, 'index.html',content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your views look, but you can just use a `for` loop in your template, like this:

```
{% for table in table_list %}
  {{table|safe}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using django's in-built views? Where is your model? Or you don't have one?

Comment: I just modified the django's in-built one. I'm sorry, but I don't get when you ask about a model. I am new in django.